# native js how to find a field name of a collection where another field equal to certain value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I know that on robomongo if I want to find _id of user where username = test2 I can use

```
db.getCollection('user').find({},{_id:1},{"username":"test2"})
```

now, on visual studio code, I want to find value of field "disabled" from user collection where field "username" value equal to variable "tempusername" value. I tried:

```
    colUser = mongoDb.collection("user");

 var status = colUser.find({},
    { disabled:1},{ username:tempusername},function (err, doc) {
        console.log(doc);
      });
```

but it shows value of status is "undefined". What is the write code for this?

Comment: Also see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). You essenentially have lots of mistakes which you can solve by taking the time and reading the documentation.

Comment: can you propose a simple sample answer that you think is correct ? that would be more helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think it's something you're looking for.

```
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
 const dbo = db.db('mydb')
 dbo.collection('user').find({disabled:'1',username:tempusername}).toArray((err, doc) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(doc)
    db.close()
 })    
})
```

Comment: I tried :  var status = colUser.find({ username:tempusername},{ _id:0,disabled:1}).toArray((err, doc) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(doc);
     }); but it return undefined. I think cannot get value like that but have to assign the value inside the function colUser.find(), am I right ?

Comment: actually I think I have to use findOne instead to get the value. But it will return something like: This is status:
n_auth_mongo.js:78
Promise { pending }
n_auth_mongo.js:78
[[PromiseStatus]]:"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]:Object
disabled:false
and here is what I want to get, but I dont know how to get that disabled:false ?

Comment: @user1314404 disabled is a type of collection or a state. I did not understand.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, basically the way it work is the result will be return inside the function, so I have to put it like this:

```
   var statusbuffer;


colUser.findOne({ username:tempusername},{ _id:0,disabled:1},function (err, userstatus){    
    // User result only available inside of this function!
    if (err) {
        next("Failed to update records");
    } else {
    console.log("disabled status here:",userstatus.disabled) // => yields your user results
    statusbuffer = userstatus.disabled;
    next();
    }
});
```

thanks all for your comments!